# Using Grid960 Text on each Other

Tags: css, html, layout, responsive-design, stylesheet

I'm trying to use Grid960 but I got some issue I got Aside text and Article mixed [image]this's my code :

```
<body class="container_12"> 
    <nav class="grid_12">
    </nav>
    <article class="grid_7 push_1">
        <h2>I'm the Article Title</h2>
        <p></p>
        <a href="#" class="btn left" name="Showme"> Show More</a>           
    </article>  
    <aside class="grid_4">
        <p> </p>
        <p></p>

    </aside>
<footer class="grid_12">
</footer>
</body>
```

Also How To make it responsive what I have to add?

Answer (score 1):

change the first article block to:

```
<article class="grid_7 prefix_1">
    <h2>I'm the Article Title</h2>
    <p></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn left" name="Showme"> Show More</a>           
</article>
```

Comment: Thx it work's like charme And for The Responsive How to dow it ?